# Rails: File in assets pipeline not found on nginx server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline

A website I am running has been experiences some crashes lately. The browser tab either goes completely white, or simply stops responding to clicks. I have only managed to associate one error in the nginx log to this failure:

```
2014/07/30 12:39:12 [error] 15032#0: *2261 open()
"/home/user_name/app_name/public/assets/application-93974c42181b2f88f4046c6f3ed118eb.js:14"
failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 80.248.18.94, serv
er: x.y.com, request: "GET
/assets/application-93974c42181b2f88f4046c6f3ed118eb.js:14 HTTP/1.0"
```

I'm actually not sure if the error is that the file isn't found, or if the error is in line 14 in the file itself. The problem with the latter is that the file is just one huge line.

EDIT: One thing to note is that memory usage of the tab containing the site keeps growing and growing after the site crashes.

I'm completely stumped so any help at all would be greatly appreciated. The error also shows up in the browser from time to time, mainly in Firefox in the form of an alert.

Comment: Did you precompile your assets? It looks like it just can't find your `application.js` file. My guess is you precompiled but didn't push up the new file or didn't issue do `rake assets:clean` after making changes locally.

Comment: Yes, my assets are precompiled, it's a part of my deployment script. rake assets:clean however, is not. I will try that, but it may take some time to see whether the error has truly gone away. In the meantime I am still very open to suggestions :)